# What is the timeout time for simple caching in AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, caching, aws-lambda

So I was finding caching solutions for my AWS Lambda functions and I find out something called 'Simple Caching'. It's fits perfectly for what I want since my data is not changed frequently. However one thing that I was unable to find that what is the timeout for this cache. When is the data refreshed by the function and is there any way I can control it ?

An example of the code I am using for the function:

```
let cachedValue;

module.exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    console.log('Starting Lambda.');

    if (!cachedValue) {
        console.log('Setting cachedValue now...');
        cachedValue = 'Foobar';
    } else {
        console.log('Cached value is already set: ', cachedValue);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing here is taking advantage of a side effect of container reuse.  There is no lower or upper bound for how long such values will persist, and no guarantee that they will persist at all.  It's a valid optimization to use, but it's entirely outside your control.

Importantly, you need to be aware that this stores the value in one single container.  It lives for as long as the Node process in the container are alive, and is accessible whenever a future invocation of the function reuses that process in that container.

If you have two or more invocations of the same function running concurrently, they will not be in the same container, and they will not see each other's global variables.  This doesn't make it an invalid technique, but you need to be aware of that fact.  The `/tmp/` directory will exhibit very similar behavior, which is why you need to clean that up when you use it.

If you throw any exception, the process and possibly the container will be destroyed, either way the cached values will be gone on the next invocation, since there's only one Node process per container.

If you don't invoke the function at all for an undefined/undocumented number of minutes, the container will be released by the service, so this goes away.

Re-deploying the function will also clear this "cache," since a new function version won't reuse containers from older function versions.

It's a perfectly valid strategy as long as you recognize that it is a feature of a black box with no user-serviceable parts.

See also https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/ -- a post that is several years old but still accurate.

Comment: I believe this method is described here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/leveraging-external-data-in-lambdaedge/ under "Fetch the data using network calls in your Lambda@Edge function / I – Cache your data in Lambda@Edge Memory" and it doesn't mention much (or anything) of this.

Comment: And trying the code snippet out from the blog post I linked, it does involve setting our own timeout time. But I found out that it seems to require setting this to false or the lambda seems to hang for the duration of the set timeout (the TTL) or something like that. `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;`